# Java excel: Get next cell in the row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to get the value of the next cell in a after a string is found. Let's say I get  A1 as the cell that contains my search string "here", I am trying to get the contents of the next cell after A1 in the row.

```
 private static String findRow(XSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                            cell = cell.getNextRowCell //made up method
                            return cell.getStringCellValue();

                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI Documentation on Iterating over Rows and Cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I figured it out.

private static String getNextRow(XSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent) {
        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim()
                            .equals(cellContent)) {
                        row = itr.next();
                        int val = cell.getColumnIndex();
                        cell = row.getCell(val);
                        String srow = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        return srow;

                    }

                }

            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```