# Java excel: Get next non-nullable cell in the same row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need help...
after iterate through all rows and cells in excel, and finding a string (code below is from here), i need to find next value in the same row, but
next value isn't in the next cell (the next few cells is empty)...

Here is the code for searching excel for a certain value:

```
 Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Row row = itr.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim()
                        .equals(cellContent)) {

// after find a string (cellContent), I need a value of next not empty cell in the same row...
```

If I use

```
cell = cellIterator.next();
```

after finding string, to positioning to the next cell in row, the exception will occur because cell is empty.

So, I don't know how to search through non-empty cells in the same row in which I founded a certain string.

Tbank you.

Comment: frome here is code which I uses to iterate through excel:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370337/java-excel-get-next-cell-in-the-row

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: if I use:
    for (Row row : sheet) {
       for (Cell cell : row) {
  after finding cell, how to move to the next cell without iterator?

Comment: Use the index based approach in the docs I pointed you to, and increment!

Comment: Any code on that? I want to do the same thing...

Comment: did you fixed this problem? @user1562652